# connection timed out; trying next origin in nslookup

Tags: linux, redhat, centos6

we are getting the below error while issuing `nslookup` command in the server.

```
nslookup testdb.oracle.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

we have added `testdb.oracle.com` in `/etc/hosts` and hostname is `test.oracle.com`.   We are tying to resolve this issue from past 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it's not working is because the command you using it wrong one for that prpose.
"nslookup" = Name Server Lookup -> it will ask your name server (listed in /etc/resolv.conf) for the information and based on the error you have not defined any name server = it doesn't work.

To check if something that only exist in /etc/host works you need to use something that uses /etc/hosts for example `ping -w2 testdb.oracle.com`, then you can see what ip that is will try to reach + if it can reach it.